# Does Diffusion Sliver protect from boardwipe spells and sacrifice spells?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a [Diffusion Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDiffusion%20Sliver%5d) out, are my Slivers protected from [Wrath of God](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWrath%20of%20God%5d)? What about [Chainer's Edict](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChainer%27s%5d%2b%5bEdict%5d)?

Comment: Although the question is different, [this answer](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32951/does-heroic-trigger-on-a-static-effect/32952#32952) applies here, too.

Comment: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/does-wrath-of-god-really-destroy-creatures-with-shroud http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14218/do-permanents-controlled-by-a-player-with-hexproof-also-have-hexproof

Answer (score 2):

**No, they are not protected**

[Diffusion Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDiffusion%20Sliver%5d)'s ability is only triggered when a Sliver becomes a 'target'. A creature is only targeted by spells or abilities that actually have the word 'target' on it. For instance, [Giant Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGiant%20Growth%5d). From the [Comprehensive rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/docs/MagicCompRules_CN2_Update_20160826.pdf):

> 114.1a An instant or sorcery spell is targeted if its spell ability identifies something it will affect by using the phrase “target [something],”

(Note that rule 114 in its entirety describes 'targeting', this is just a specific excerpt for instants and sorceries.)

The Sliver needs to be identified as that '*target [something]*' in order for this specific ability to trigger. On instants and sorceries, this is spelled out; casting an Aura (ie [Unholy Strength](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnholy%20Strength%5d)) on a Sliver also triggers the ability added to it by Diffusion Sliver, as they have an implicit target:

> 114.1b Aura spells are always targeted.

Casting an equipment would not trigger the ability, as they enter play unattached and not targeting anything.  Their equip-ability however *would* count as becoming a target.

To look a little closer at what spells do and do not target the Slivers:

- [Twiddle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTwiddle%5d) would target the Sliver and trigger this ability.
- [Turnabout](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTurnabout%5d) wouldn't, because the card doesn't target a creature, it targets a player.
- [Call to Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCall%20to%20Glory%5d) would not target the Sliver, as it doesn't target anything.

Answer (score 1):

No, the key word here is "target". Your slivers get an ability that triggers whenevery a spell or ability gets cast/activated that contains the word "target", e.g. Doom Blade. Any spells/abilities which do not "target" your slivers are uneffected by diffusion sliver, as here in your example edicts don't target your creatures but you and wrath doesn't target at all.